# Disable "Bluetooth Permission Request" confirmation on Android - using ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcast, bluetooth-device-discovery

I'm trying to broadcast my Android phone as a Bluetooth server, and to do so, I first want to make the Android "Discoverable".

I'm doing so using ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE, as shown here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#EnablingDiscoverability

```
 testIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
 startActivity(testIntent);
```

Unfortunately, this also pops up a "Bluetooth Permission Request" dialog on the phone.

Is there any way to make my phone "Discoverable", without having to prompt the user?

Thanks!

Comment: There might be, but as users do we really want to have other apps activating our Bluetooth without us knowing?

Answer (score 0):

Try including the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission to your applicaiton

Comment: Seems like you cant override the user dialog when using Intents .. the workaround is to use reflection and on a rooted phone you can use reflection to call the setScanMode method of BluetoothService see this thread... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6348#c34

Comment: I can't root the phone for this application... Thanks anyway.

Comment: have u found a solution yet?

Comment: yeah, I'd like to do this too. I see why they force the popup, they don't want a rogue application turning on visibility without the user's awareness, but if an app needs to do it to function, it's impossible without the popup.

Comment: I think an alternative is to try and downgrade android from lollipop to whatever I had before which allowed me to set bluetooth visibility on all the time. They recently removed that feature so now the phone is only bluetooth-visible while you're on the bluetooth settings page. Yay progress. Breaking things at the speed of light.